# How do I preserve all tags, structure and text in an xml document replacing only some with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I've been trying to apply a simple xsl style to an xml document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>

        <xsl:for-each select="//title">
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, this seems to just simply ignore all other tags and remove them as well as their contents from the output, and I'm only left with titles converted to h1s. What I would like to be able to do is to have my document's structure remain, while replacing only some of its tags.

So that for example if I have this document:

```
<section>
  <title>Hello world</title>
  <p>Hello!</p>
</section>
```

I could get this:

```
<section>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <p>Hello!</p>
</section>
```

No quite sure where in the XSLT manual to start looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As O. R. Mapper says, the solution to this is to add an identity template to your transform and just override the parts you need to.  This would be the complete solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()" />
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Hello!</p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you really just want to preserve your original XML but replace the `<title>`, you can just remove the middle `<xsl:template>` and you should get the result:

```
<section>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <p>Hello!</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace just `<title>` elements. However, in your XSLT, you define a template for the root element (`/`) of your document, and you *replace* the entire root element with the contents of your template.

What you *actually* want to do is define an identity transform template (google this, it's an important concept in XSLT) to copy basically everything from your source document, and a template that *only* matches your `<title>` elements and replaces them with your new code, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I would drop the leading `//` in the `<xsl:template match="//title">` pattern, it is not necessary in a pattern. Writing `<xsl:template match="title">` does the job just fine.

Comment: It would also be preferable to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="." />`, since there could be child nodes or attributes.  +1 for having the right idea.