# XSLT empty tags are not included in output

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am transforming an XML to another format. Input XML include table which have empty cells.
Input is:

```
<cals:tbody>
                        <cals:row>
                            <ce:entry>
                                <ce:italic>P. andensis</ce:italic> Vitik.
                            </ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry>+</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry>+</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry align="char" char=".">2</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry align="char" char=".">1</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry align="char" char=".">1</ce:entry>
                        </cals:row>
                        <cals:row>
                            <ce:entry>
                                <ce:italic>P. aphthosa</ce:italic> (L.) Willd.
                            </ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry>+</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry>+</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry>+</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry>+</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry/>
                            <ce:entry align="char" char=".">41</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry align="char" char=".">8</ce:entry>
                            <ce:entry align="char" char=".">3</ce:entry>
                        </cals:row>
                        </cals:tbody>
```

my xslt code is :

```
<xsl:for-each select="/TBODY/ROW">

                                            <tr>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="./ENTRY">

                                                <xsl:element name="td">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                                                </xsl:element>

                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                           </tr>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                    </xsl:choose>

                                </xsl:for-each>
```

Output do not have `td` tags for corresponding empty `entry` tag.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I preserve all tags, structure and text in an xml document replacing only some with XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662409/how-do-i-preserve-all-tags-structure-and-text-in-an-xml-document-replacing-only)

Comment: This question has different scenario. Not duplicate

Comment: It's a duplicate insofar as the solution will be to use the Identity Transform just as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `namespaces`. In your sample XML, you have `cals` and `ce`. Also you have incorrect casing in your xpaths.

change

```
<xsl:for-each select="/TBODY/ROW">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="/cals:tbody/cals:row">
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="./ENTRY">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="./ce:entry">
```

Comment: I have removed namespace when parsing xml using Java. This is not the case.

Comment: Even if you have removed the namespace in Java, the casing in your input XML and your stylesheet snippet will not match.